# PyGame won't load the images on window and crashes immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I was making a game in python with pygame and I had some assets as characters. I coded everything correctly. But when I run the program none of the images show up and the window crashes immediately.

```
import pygame
import os
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Fly game")

FPS = 60
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

FPS = 60
VEL = 5
BORDER = pygame.Rect(WIDTH//2 - 5, 0, 10, HEIGHT)
PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT = 55, 40

SKY = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Kostadin Klemov\\Desktop\\Programms\\Python\\projects\\Fly game\\Assets\\SKY.jpg')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT)


JETPACK_MAN_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Kostadin Klemov\\Desktop\\Programms\\Python\\projects\\Fly game\\Assets\\JETPACK_MAN.jpg'))
JETPACK_MAN = pygame.transform.scale(
    JETPACK_MAN_IMAGE, (PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT))

FLY_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Kostadin Klemov\\Desktop\\Programms\\Python\\projects\\Fly game\\Assets\\FLY.png'))
FLY = pygame.transform.scale(
    FLY_IMAGE, (PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT))


def draw_window(jetpack, fly):
    WIN.blit(SKY, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, BORDER)
    
    WIN.blit(JETPACK_MAN, (jetpack.x, jetpack.y))
    WIN.blit(FLY, (fly.x, fly.y))

    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    jetpack = pygame.Rect(225, 250, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)
    fly = pygame.Rect(675, 250, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                
                draw_window(jetpack, fly)

    main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main
```

No error showed up so I didn't know what was wrong.
If you can, please check out the code and try to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation error.

```py
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        # <---- INDENTATION
        # this should be in the while loop, the "game loop", not in the quit condition
        draw_window(jetpack, fly)
```

Also, you probably don't want to call main() after you program terminates. (Assuming you want people to be able to exit your game easily.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main
```

This `main` does nothing, it needs to be called, like `main()`. With the parentheses. It's not "crashing instantly," it's just not running anything.

```py
SKY = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Kostadin Klemov\\Desktop\\Programms\\Python\\projects\\Fly game\\Assets\\SKY.jpg')), (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

That (WIDTH, HEIGHT) at the end is very suspicious. Presumably you just want the image put in the `SKY` variable, not another random tuple.

On another note, `os.path.join()` does nothing if you give it the full path as an argument.